# c# simple switch

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Feel like an idiot :)  Why does this not work?

```
switch (sortCol)
{
case: "username"
    mnu_username.Text = "";
    break;
case default
    break;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully the weekend will invigorate our tired eyes :)

Comment: I don't know who down-voted you, but here's a +1 :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
switch (sortCol)
{
    case "username":
        mnu_username.Text = "";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Have you not got an IDE to highlight syntax errors for you?
Also note that if `sortCol` is not a string, this won't work.

Comment: Perfect thanks, yes it did highlight errors in VS2008 but they were not very helpful for switch statements

Comment: Ahh I see :) I've on some occasions reverted back to the Pascal case statements and scratched my head for a few moments until I realise I missed `switch`. Fridays...

Answer (score 5):

`case default` should be changed to `default:`. Then your switch statement should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (sortCol)
            {
                case "username":
                    mnu_username.Text = "<img src=\"../images/" + sortType + ".png\" class=\"adIco\" />";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```